# Exception android::uirenderer::RenderNode::prepareTree

Tags: android, segmentation-fault

We are facing a weird exception on our native Android app. Actually we have no idea how to reproduce it or where does it occurs, we have only the stacktrace caught by Sentry:

> OS Version: Android 10 (QP1A.190711.020.A013MUBU3AVC1) Report Version:
> 104
>
> Exception Type: Unknown (SIGSEGV)
>
> Application Specific Information: Segfault
>
> Thread 0 Crashed: 0   libhwui.so                      0xb1037ed6
>  + 2969796310 1   libhwui.so                      0xb1037f9f
> [inlined]  + 2969796511 2   libhwui.so
> 0xb1037f9f          [inlined]  + 2969796511 3   libhwui.so
> 0xb1037f9f          [inlined]  + 2969796511 4   libhwui.so
> 0xb1037f9f          [inlined]  + 2969796511 5   libhwui.so
> 0xb1037f9f          [inlined]  + 2969796511 6   libhwui.so
> 0xb1037f9f          [inlined]  + 2969796511 7   libhwui.so
> 0xb1037f9f          [inlined]  + 2969796511 8   libhwui.so
> 0xb1037f9f          [inlined]  + 2969796511 9   libhwui.so
> 0xb1037f9f          [inlined]  + 2969796511 10  libhwui.so
> 0xb1037f9f          [inlined]  + 2969796511 11  libhwui.so
> 0xb1037f9f           + 2969796511 12  libhwui.so
> 0xb10a7435          android::uirenderer::RenderNode::prepareTree 13
> libandroid_runtime.so           0xb31ac71b           +
> 3004876571 14  libhwui.so                      0xb10b3e8b
>  + 2970304139 15  libhwui.so                      0xb10b3c47
>  + 2970303559 16  libhwui.so                      0xb10b38bf
>  + 2970302655 17  libhwui.so                      0xb10bf041
>  + 2970349633 18  libhwui.so                      0xb10beea1
>  + 2970349217 19  libutils.so                     0xb30168b1
> android::Thread::_threadLoop 20  libc.so
> 0xb24de095           + 2991448213 21  libc.so
> 0xb2498765           + 2991163237 22  
> 0x0
>
> EOF

Does anyone have any idea of what can be happening?

THanks a lot!